# "Where to publish" questions: on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Are questions asking about venues for publishing statistical or machine learning-related articles on-topic at CV? Here is an example: [Where to publish reasonable article in Deep Reinforcement Learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312400/1352)

Just for reference: [Suggestions or recommendations for a university, journal, or research topic (a "shopping question") are explicitly off-topic at Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

I'll provide answers, please upvote as you see fit, or add a new answer.

Comment: Just adding a note that poll-like Meta questions are usually not a good idea. It's preferable to leave the question open so that everyone can voice their opinions, and elaborate on and justify them too — see these two posts by Robert on MSE, elaborating on why, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233943/208518) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279267/208518).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No**, questions about venues for publishing statistical or ML articles are off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, questions about venues for publishing statistical or ML articles are on-topic.